# PostgreSQL server install - can't find or access dll

Tags: windows, postgresql

When i try to install postgresql-9.0.4-1-windows.exe, somewhere at the
end of the installation i get an error.
"... libintl-8.dll was not found ..."

[image: Error installing PostgreSQL server]

(same as in this thread: http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/2526.page
 direct link:
http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/downloadAttach/147.page;jsessionid=43B371483530826B5E7EE9151F79279C )

Everything i found concerning this error suggests a permissions issue
of the Windows user account, but i was logged in as Administrator.
I tried to install the PostgreSQL server on another disk than the
default (D:\Apps), together with the data directory. The data
directory was created and the concerning dll (libintl-8.dll) was
present.

Consequences are that the PostgreSQL Windows service cannot be started.

I am not a Windows expert, so my question is two-fold:

- can an administrator have diminished privileges causing this error?
- can this error have another cause than priviliges, which?

Thanks in advance for any insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see from screenshot it's issue related to [initdb,exe](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html), which creates/initializes new database cluster. As PostgreSQL documentation stays:

> initdb must be run as the user that
>   will own the server process, because
>   the server needs to have access to the
>   files and directories that initdb
>   creates. Since the server cannot be
>   run as root, you must not run initdb
>   as root either. (It will in fact
>   refuse to do so.)

According to [installer's](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide) doc there should be `install-postgresql.log` logfile in your `%TEMP%`, so you can get more info (additional there is `--debuglevel` installer option, run with `--help` to see more description).

> If you encounter any problems during
>   installation, please check the logfile
>   that is created in /tmp on Linux or
>   Mac OS X or %TEMP% on Windows. The
>   file will be called
>   install-postgresql.log. The logfile
>   may contain the superuser password you
>   specified during the installation,
>   which should be replaced before
>   sharing the log with anyone.

Are you using default postgres superuser/service account ? I don't know if this helps, but you try to remove it before (clean) installation by (using cmd with admin rights):

```
net user postgres /del
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because you are logged in as Administrator doesn't mean you can access all files - it just means you can give yourself the privileges to access every file.

Check the privileges on the DLL in question and make sure the user that runs the installation and the postgres service account have both read privileges on that file

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:  I was able to follow the below successfully installing Postgres 9.4.x on Windows Server 2008, too.

I had the same mentioned libint-8.dll and other problems installing Postgres 9.0.x on Windows Server 2008 (details: running installer as admin, with choice to install as service using a service account).

What I had to do to get things to work:

1. In the end, I only used one level of directory for where I installed the
   executable (and also for the data directory).  I had been trying to
   create a folder structure wherein the executable was a couple of
   folders deep, so I was specifying folderA/folderB/finalfolder.  Some
   page I found while googling suggested not to do that, but to create
   one folder level at most.  (I tried to go back through my browser
   history to find that page, since it seems like it solved my problem
   and I want to give credit.  But I couldn't find the page again).
2. Based on other frustrated people's suggested solutions to
   permissions problems, I also started out by giving "Everyone" complete
   control over the installation directory and the data directory. 
   However, those other solutions neglected to mention the next step,
   which is important for security:
3. Then, **and this is important for security**, once the install
   worked under the combination of the above two points, I added read &
   execute for the postgres service account on the executable folder
   (and below), and modify|write|read on the data folder.  I then
   stripped the rights I had given "Everyone".  I restarted the
   database service and it still worked, but now without the rather
   insecure seeming permissions for Everyone.

Rather painful all in all.  It took 2-3 hours to hit on the combination that appeared to work.

Answer (score -2):

I had exactly the same problem. Tried to install PostgreSQL in my user folder (using admin rights). Same problem.

**Solution**: Install in `C:\PostgreSQL` , without using subdirectories. Did work for me immediately.